# "Message: invalid data; odd-length - 0x0" error, solidity or javascript error

Tags: javascript, string, testing, solidity, remix

We wrote a Smart Contract in Solidity language. It has a function taking a string as one of it's arguments. We also wrote unit tests for the functions. The unit test for a function I mentioned just yet gives an error as follows:

```
Message: invalid data; odd-length - 0x0.
```

How can we fix the issue?

We are certain it gives error due to this argument being string because the call doesn't enter the solidity function at all; we did console.log() and it didn't log . We are developing in Remix compiler.

//the call I make from js test code, user_account2 being an address:

```
await mygov.connect(user_account2).submitSurvey("abc", 21e6 , 3 , 2);
```

//the function from the solidity smart contract:

```
function submitSurvey(string memory ipfshash,uint surveydeadline,uint numchoices, uint atmostchoice) public returns (uint surveyid) {
    User storage owner = users[msg.sender]; 
    require(isMember(owner), "1");
    require(owner.myGovTokens >=2, "2");
    require(owner.myGovTokens >2  || owner.myGovTokensLockedUntil <= block.timestamp, "3"); 
    uint[] memory results = new uint[](numchoices) ; 


    Survey memory mysurvey = Survey({
                Ipfshash : ipfshash,
                Owner: msg.sender,
                Deadline: surveydeadline,
                SurveyId: surveyid,
                AtmostChoice: atmostchoice,
                NumChoices: numchoices,
                NumTaken : 0,
                Results : results         
                });
    

    transferToken(address(this), 2);  
    address payable to_sc = payable(address(this));
    
    transfer(to_sc, surveyCreationFee); 
    donatedWei += surveyCreationFee; 

    surveys.push(mysurvey);
    surveyid = surveys.length - 1 ; 
    mysurvey.SurveyId = surveyid;
    return (surveyid);
}
```

Comment: Please share the code!

Comment: you should paste the code to the original post in order to get help. Also, pls paste the relevant contract code.

Comment: since you say "because the call doesn't enter the solidity function at all;", first line of code might cause issue. Remove this line: `User storage owner = users[msg.sender]; ` and add this. `require(2=1,"Invalid equation")` if you get this error message that means it is because of first line

Comment: or actually just add this to the beginning of the fn: `require(2=1,"Invalid equation")`

Comment: I tried console.log("Some message") as soon as entering the submitSurvey method; that would have been reached if it was a problem related with the interior of the solidity function but it wasn't logged. I tried what you recommended anyway but they didn't change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When I've faced the same issue the solution was to use signer instance instead of address:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3Provider);
const owner = provider.getSigner(0);
const user_account2 = provider.getSigner(1);
```

As per [documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v4/api-contract.html?highlight=connect#creating-a-contract-factory):

> prototype . connect ( signer )   =>   ContractFactory Create a new
> instance of the ContractFactory, connected to the new signer.